# Python extract information from html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html page as such, basically it's the right side box of wikipedia about Microsoft [wiki site][1]:

```html
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="logo" colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
            <a class="image" href="/wiki/File:Microsoft_logo_(2012).svg" title="A square divided into four sub-squares, colored red, green, yellow and blue (clockwise), with the company name appearing to its right."><img alt="A square divided into four sub-squares, colored red, green, yellow and blue (clockwise), with the company name appearing to its right." data-file-height="109" data-file-width="512" decoding="async" height="47" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg/220px-Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg/330px-Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg/440px-Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg.png 2x" width="220" /></a>
            <div>Microsoft's logo since 2012</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="logo" colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
            <a class="image" href="/wiki/File:Building92microsoft.jpg"><img alt="Building92microsoft.jpg" data-file-height="3456" data-file-width="5184" decoding="async" height="147" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Building92microsoft.jpg/220px-Building92microsoft.jpg" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Building92microsoft.jpg/330px-Building92microsoft.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Building92microsoft.jpg/440px-Building92microsoft.jpg 2x" width="220" /></a>
            <div>Building 92 on the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Redmond_campus" title="Microsoft Redmond campus">Microsoft Redmond campus</a> in <a href="/wiki/Redmond,_Washington" title="Redmond, Washington">Redmond, Washington</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
            <div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;"><a href="/wiki/List_of_legal_entity_types_by_country" title="List of legal entity types by country">Type</a></div>
        </th>
        <td class="category" style="line-height:1.35em;"><a href="/wiki/Public_company" title="Public company">Public</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;"><a href="/wiki/Ticker_symbol" title="Ticker symbol">Traded as</a></th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;">
            <div class="plainlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/NASDAQ" title="NASDAQ">NASDAQ</a>: <a class="external text" href="https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft" rel="nofollow">MSFT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/NASDAQ-100" title="NASDAQ-100">NASDAQ-100</a> component</li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average" title="Dow Jones Industrial Average">DJIA</a> component</li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/S%26P_100" title="S&amp;P 100">S&amp;P 100</a> component</li>
                    <li><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/S%26P_500" title="S&amp;P 500">S&amp;P 500</a> component</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;"><a href="/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number" title="International Securities Identification Number">ISIN</a></th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><span class="plainlinks nourlexpansion"><a class="external text" href="https://tools.wmflabs.org/isin/?language=de&amp;isin=US5949181045">US5949181045</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Industry</th>
        <td class="category" style="line-height:1.35em;">
            <div class="plainlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Computer_software" title="Computer software">Computer software</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Computer_hardware" title="Computer hardware">Computer hardware</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Consumer_electronics" title="Consumer electronics">Consumer electronics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Social_networking_service" title="Social networking service">Social networking service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Cloud_computing" title="Cloud computing">Cloud computing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Video_game_industry" title="Video game industry">Video games</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Internet" title="Internet">Internet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Corporate_venture_capital" title="Corporate venture capital">Corporate venture capital</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Founded</th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;">April 4, 1975<span class="noprint">; 44 years ago</span><span style="display:none"> (<span class="bday dtstart published updated">1975-04-04</span>)</span> in <a href="/wiki/Albuquerque,_New_Mexico" title="Albuquerque, New Mexico">Albuquerque, New Mexico</a>, U.S.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Founders</th>
        <td class="agent" style="line-height:1.35em;">
            <div class="plainlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Bill_Gates" title="Bill Gates">Bill Gates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Paul_Allen" title="Paul Allen">Paul Allen</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Headquarters</th>
        <td class="label" style="line-height:1.35em;"><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Redmond_campus" title="Microsoft Redmond campus">One Microsoft Way</a>,
            <div class="locality" style="display:inline"><a href="/wiki/Redmond,_Washington" title="Redmond, Washington">Redmond</a>, <a href="/wiki/Washington_(state)" title="Washington (state)">Washington</a></div>,
            <div class="country-name" style="display:inline">U.S.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
            <div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;">Area served</div>
        </th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;">Worldwide</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
            <div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;">Key people</div>
        </th>
        <td class="agent" style="line-height:1.35em;">
            <div class="plainlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/John_W._Thompson" title="John W. Thompson">John W. Thompson</a>
                        <br/>(<a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Chairman" title="Chairman">Chairman</a>)</li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Satya_Nadella" title="Satya Nadella">Satya Nadella</a>
                        <br/>(<a href="/wiki/Chief_executive_officer" title="Chief executive officer">CEO</a>)</li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Brad_Smith_(American_lawyer)" title="Brad Smith (American lawyer)">Brad Smith</a>
                        <br/>(<a href="/wiki/President_(corporate_title)" title="President (corporate title)">President</a>)</li>
                    <li>Bill Gates
                        <br/>(<a href="/wiki/Technical_advisor" title="Technical advisor">Technical Advisor</a>)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Products</th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;">
            <div class="hlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Windows" title="Microsoft Windows">Windows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Office" title="Microsoft Office">Office</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Servers" title="Microsoft Servers">Servers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Skype" title="Skype">Skype</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio" title="Microsoft Visual Studio">Visual Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics" title="Microsoft Dynamics">Dynamics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Xbox" title="Xbox">Xbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Surface" title="Microsoft Surface">Surface</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Mobile" title="Microsoft Mobile">Mobile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_software" title="List of Microsoft software">List of software</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Services</th>
        <td class="category" style="line-height:1.35em;">
            <div class="hlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Azure" title="Microsoft Azure">Azure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Bing_(search_engine)" title="Bing (search engine)">Bing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network" title="Microsoft Developer Network">MSDN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Office_365" title="Office 365">Office 365</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/OneDrive" title="OneDrive">OneDrive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Outlook.com" title="Outlook.com">Outlook.com</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_TechNet" title="Microsoft TechNet">TechNet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Pay" title="Microsoft Pay">Pay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Store_(digital)" title="Microsoft Store (digital)">Microsoft Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Windows_Update" title="Windows Update">Windows Update</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wiki/Xbox_Live" title="Xbox Live">Xbox Live</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Revenue</th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><img alt="Increase" data-file-height="300" data-file-width="300" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" title="Increase" width="11" /> <span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="/wiki/United_States_dollar" title="United States dollar">US$</a>125.8 billion</span><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-ER-FY19_1-0"><a href="#cite_note-ER-FY19-1">[1]</a></sup> (2019)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
            <div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;"><a href="/wiki/Earnings_before_interest_and_taxes" title="Earnings before interest and taxes">Operating income</a></div>
        </th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><img alt="Increase" data-file-height="300" data-file-width="300" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" title="Increase" width="11" /> <span style="white-space: nowrap">US$43.0 billion</span><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-ER-FY19_1-1"><a href="#cite_note-ER-FY19-1">[1]</a></sup> (2019)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
            <div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;"><a href="/wiki/Net_income" title="Net income">Net income</a></div>
        </th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><img alt="Increase" data-file-height="300" data-file-width="300" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" title="Increase" width="11" /> <span style="white-space: nowrap">US$39.2 billion</span><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-ER-FY19_1-2"><a href="#cite_note-ER-FY19-1">[1]</a></sup> (2019)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;"><span class="nowrap"><a href="/wiki/Asset" title="Asset">Total assets</a></span></th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><img alt="Increase" data-file-height="300" data-file-width="300" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" title="Increase" width="11" /> <span style="white-space: nowrap">US$286.55 billion</span><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-ER-FY19_1-3"><a href="#cite_note-ER-FY19-1">[1]</a></sup> (2019)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;"><span class="nowrap"><a href="/wiki/Equity_(finance)" title="Equity (finance)">Total equity</a></span></th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><img alt="Increase" data-file-height="300" data-file-width="300" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" title="Increase" width="11" /> <span style="white-space: nowrap">US$102.33 billion</span><sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-ER-FY19_1-4"><a href="#cite_note-ER-FY19-1">[1]</a></sup> (2019)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
            <div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;">Number of employees</div>
        </th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><img alt="Increase" data-file-height="300" data-file-width="300" decoding="async" height="11" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" title="Increase" width="11" /> 144,106<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-2"><a href="#cite_note-2">[2]</a></sup> (2019)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;"><a href="/wiki/Subsidiary" title="Subsidiary">Subsidiaries</a></th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><a href="/wiki/List_of_mergers_and_acquisitions_by_Microsoft" title="List of mergers and acquisitions by Microsoft">List of Microsoft assets</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">Website</th>
        <td style="line-height:1.35em;"><span class="url"><a class="external text" href="https://www.microsoft.com/" rel="nofollow">microsoft.com</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

How can I make a table like this out these html code:

I tried to use pandas read_html, if failed. Then I used beautifulsoup, it has many tags, and in some cases, wiki has more different tags other than these in Microsoft page. **Basiclly, I want to extract the very inner text of the tags. How could I do this using python, and considering potentially many more different tags** .
[![How can I make a table like this out these html code][2]][2]
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW38L.png

Comment: for every page you may have to create new code with `beautifulsoup`

Comment: No matter, let me try to use soup.get_text()

Comment: `beautifulsoup` has `get_text()` to get all text in tag - even from sub-tags. But if you want to get only text from sub-tag then you have to use `find()` to get it.

Comment: How did you use `pandas.read_html()` ? it seems it get all text from right table but rows are not splitted to many rows as you need. - `pd.read_html(url)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Code:

It uses `BeautifulSoup` to find first table and `th` `td` in every row.

Some `td` have `li` which need next loop.

```
# https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/
# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_tables = soup.find_all('table')

all_rows = all_tables[0].find_all('tr')
for row in all_rows:

    th = row.find('th')
    if not th:
        continue

    title = th.text

    td = row.find('td')
    all_li = td.find_all('li')

    if all_li:
        for item in all_li:
            print(title, '>', item.get_text())
    else:
        print(title, '>', td.get_text())
```

Result:

```
Type > Public
Traded as > NASDAQ: MSFT
Traded as > NASDAQ-100 component
Traded as > DJIA component
Traded as > S&P 100 component
Traded as > S&P 500 component
ISIN > US5949181045
Industry > Computer software
Industry > Computer hardware
Industry > Consumer electronics
Industry > Social networking service
Industry > Cloud computing
Industry > Video games
Industry > Internet
Industry > Corporate venture capital
Founded > April 4, 1975; 44 years ago (1975-04-04) in Albuquerque, New Mexico, U.S.
Founders > Bill Gates
Founders > Paul Allen
Headquarters > One Microsoft Way, Redmond, Washington, U.S.
Area served > Worldwide
Key people > John W. Thompson(Chairman)
Key people > Satya Nadella(CEO)
Key people > Brad Smith(President)
Key people > Bill Gates(Technical Advisor)
Products > Windows
Products > Office
Products > Servers
Products > Skype
Products > Visual Studio
Products > Dynamics
Products > Xbox
Products > Surface
Products > Mobile
Products > List of software
Services > Azure
Services > Bing
Services > LinkedIn
Services > MSDN
Services > Office 365
Services > OneDrive
Services > Outlook.com
Services > TechNet
Services > Pay
Services > Microsoft Store
Services > Windows Update
Services > Xbox Live
Revenue >  US$125.8 billion[1] (2019)
Operating income >  US$43.0 billion[1] (2019)
Net income >  US$39.2 billion[1] (2019)
Total assets >  US$286.55 billion[1] (2019)
Total equity >  US$102.33 billion[1] (2019)
Number of employees >  144,106[2] (2019)
Subsidiaries > List of Microsoft assets
Website > microsoft.com
```

Some lines still need individual cleaning. There is no one rule for all of them so they will need individual code.

Comment: Thanks furas, I used pd.read_html(), but this is valuable too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to get the same results. A little cleaning to do, though.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft"

res = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
for items in soup.find('table',class_='vcard').find_all('tr'):
    [i.extract() for i in items.select("a[href^='#cite']")]
    data = items.find_all(['th','td'])
    title = data[0].text
    if not len(data)>=2:continue
    product = ' '.join([' '.join(item.split()) for item in data[1].strings]).strip()
    print("{} | {}".format(title,product))
```

Output:

```
Type | Public
Traded as | NASDAQ : MSFT NASDAQ-100 component DJIA component S&P 100 component S&P 500 component
ISIN | US5949181045
Industry | Computer software Computer hardware Consumer electronics Social networking service Cloud computing Video games Internet Corporate venture capital
Founded | April 4, 1975 ; 44 years ago ( 1975-04-04 ) in Albuquerque, New Mexico , U.S.
Founders | Bill Gates  Paul Allen
Headquarters | One Microsoft Way , Redmond , Washington , U.S.
Area served | Worldwide
Key people | John W. Thompson ( Chairman )  Satya Nadella ( CEO )  Brad Smith ( President )  Bill Gates ( Technical Advisor )
Products | Windows  Office  Servers  Skype  Visual Studio  Dynamics  Xbox  Surface  Mobile  List of software
Services | Azure  Bing  LinkedIn  MSDN  Office 365  OneDrive  Outlook.com  TechNet  Pay  Microsoft Store  Windows Update  Xbox Live
Revenue | US$ 125.8 billion (2019)
Operating income | US$43.0 billion (2019)
Net income | US$39.2 billion (2019)
Total assets | US$286.55 billion (2019)
Total equity | US$102.33 billion (2019)
Number of employees | 144,106 (2019)
Subsidiaries | List of Microsoft assets
Website | microsoft.com
```

Comment: if you can split text in `Industry`, `Founders`, `Key people`, `Produce`, `Services` to lists with separated elements  like on web page then it could be even more useful.